# How to echo inside an echo?

Tags: php

Here's a copy of my current code:

```
  echo '<td style="word-wrap: break-word;">
     <div><center><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#489FDC;" href="http://local.mysite.com/'.echo basename(__DIR__);.'/'.strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$row[cities])).'">'.ucwords($row[cities]).'</a></center></div>
   </td>';
```

But I am getting this error and can't figure out how to fix it:

```
[21-Feb-2014 11:46:08 America/Chicago] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /home/username/public_html/local/advertising-company/index.php on line 196
```

I know it has something to do with this part of the code:

`'.echo basename(__DIR__);.'`

What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: Just leave out the second `echo` - `"abc".basename(__DIR__)."def"` is what you should do.

Comment: That's inceptionous thinking, sir.

Comment: Write a PHP function to format your data instead of slapping a glob of PHP inside your HTML. If you ever need to do maintenance on such an obfuscated code, you will waste time trying to figure out what it actually does and probably end up rewriting it from scratch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Using a variable inside a double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512452/php-using-a-variable-inside-a-double-quotes)

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate... But only isn't because the OP doesn't know what he's saying. The answer is in that questions answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10512466/1596138)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the other one,

```
echo '<td style="word-wrap: break-word;">
      <div><center><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#489FDC;" 
      href="http://local.mysite.com/'.basename(__DIR__).
      '/'.strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$row[cities])).'">'.
      ucwords($row[cities]).'</a></center></div>
      </td>';
```

Comment: That causese this error:  `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/username/public_html/local/advertising-company/index.php on line 195`

Comment: Are you sure you removed `echo` along with `;` ?

Comment: Still make sure. Or create a [fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/) for us.

Comment: The ';' appears to have been causing the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove second `echo`
2. Use quotes for array elements: `$row[cities]` should be `$row['cities']`

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do echo inside echo you can do as

```
echo '<td style="word-wrap: break-word;">
     <div><center><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#489FDC;" href="http://local.mysite.com/'.basename(__DIR__).'/'.strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$row[cities])).'">'.ucwords($row[cities]).'</a></center></div>
   </td>';
```

Comment: That causese this error:  `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/username/public_html/local/advertising-company/index.php on line 195`

Comment: This should work I just tested !!

Comment: @user3286482v you have an error on line 195. Is that where this line is? If you're working with ~200 lines of code and clearly have no idea what you're doing it's going to be next to impossible to tell what your problem actually is. You don't even know.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<td style="word-wrap: break-word;">
 <div><center><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#489FDC;" href="http://local.mysite.com/'.basename(__DIR__).'/'.strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$row[cities])).'">'.ucwords($row[cities]).'</a></center></div>
```

';

Move the second echo, and it will show.

Comment: That causese this error:  `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/username/public_html/local/advertising-company/index.php on line 195`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to call echo, you need just concatenate strings, ie.:

```
echo '<td style="word-wrap: break-word;">
     <div><center><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#489FDC;" href="http://local.mysite.com/'.basename(__DIR__).'/'.strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$row[cities])).'">'.ucwords($row[cities]).'</a></center></div>
   </td>';
```

Comment: That causese this error:  `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/username/public_html/local/advertising-company/index.php on line 195`

Comment: you are wrong - it's working ok or you have another error

Answer (score 0):

lol.  :)

Just use the method call.

```
echo " SOME STRING " . basename(__DIR__)  . " SOMESTRING ";
```

Answer (score 0):

The index variable should be within single quotes.

```
echo '<td style="word-wrap: break-word;">
<div>
<center>
<a style="text-decoration:none;color:#489FDC;" href="http://local.mysite.com /"'.basename(__DIR__).'"/'.strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$row['cities'])).'">'.ucwords($row['cities']).'</a>
</center>
</div>';
```

Answer (score -1):

try this...

`echo "<td style='word-wrap: break-word;'>
     <div><center><a style='text-decoration:none;color:#489FDC;' href='http://local.mysite.com/'".basename(__DIR__)."'/'".strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$row[cities]))."''>'".ucwords($row[cities])."'</a></center></div>
   </td>";`

Comment: That caused this error:  `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/username/public_html/local/advertising-company/index.php on line 195`

Comment: You don't need to echo inside of an echo!!!

Comment: How is this supposed to work? You can't concatenate echo as if it was a string or function