# Query result into variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I'm making a website. I want it so that I can put records into the database via my website. So first I need to select the id from which record I want to change. Then I want to put the values of the selected id into a variable. The I want to put the variable into a form value.
I'm trying to make something similar to phpmyadmin. If you click on the pencil you go to a form were everything is complete and you can just change the things you want to change and save it into the database.
wijzigen.php:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="set_wijziging.php">
  <h1>Selecteer het vuurwerkid van het product dat u wilt wijzigen</h1>
  <p>Vuurwerkid <br>
    <input  type="text" name="vuurwerkid" id="vuurwerkid" />

  <input type="submit" name="wijzigen" id="wijzigen" value="wijzigen"/>
</form>
```

and here is the part were I put what I typed in in the form into a variable.

```
<?php
$vuurwerkid=$_POST["vuurwerkid"];
?>
```

Then I'm trying to make a query wich only selects the things were vuurwerkid='$vuurwerkid'
So here I try to put the results of the query into a variable. But this doesn't seem to work.
set_wijziging.php:

```
 <?php
                include("connect.php");
            $vuurwerkid=$_POST["vuurwerkid"];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM vuurwerk_info WERE vuurwerkid='$vuurwerkid'";
        $resultaat = MySQL_query($query);
    while ($row = MySQL_fetch_array($resultaat))
    {
    $vuurwerkid="$row["vuurwerkid"]";
    $naam=$row["naam"];
    $prijs=$row["prijs"];
    $soort=$row["soort"]; 
    $cat_vuurwerk=$row["cat_vuurwerk"]; 
    $aantal=$row["aantal"]; 


}
?>
```

I'm just started learning PHP

Comment: Can you read the post variable correctly

Comment: If you're just starting to learn PHP, please be wise and look into PDO immediately and discard the mysql_* functions. They will be deprecated soon, and if you're new and learning you'd better start learning the 'new' way.

Comment: Little Bobby Tables -- http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` spelling is wrong in your `query`

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM vuurwerk_info WHERE vuurwerkid='$vuurwerkid'";
```

I miss that last time Change this line as well

`$vuurwerkid="$row["vuurwerkid"]";`

To this

```
`$vuurwerkid=$row["vuurwerkid"];

//Remove the Double queite. As its variable not string`
```

although `function` name are **case-incensitiv**e. But change theese lines as well

chnage this

```
$resultaat = MySQL_query($query);
    while ($row = MySQL_fetch_array($resultaat))
```

To this

```
$resultaat = mysql_query($query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat))
```

**`Note`** I change nothing in the below line. I just used the small letter to right those function

Please learn **MYSQLI_** OR **PDO**

As mysql function are depriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your $query to

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM vuurwerk_info WHERE vuurwerkid='$vuurwerkid'";
```

Also try to echo your query to see if it's correct.
Finally as others pointed out you should stop using mysql_* and switch to msqli or PDO.

Comment: If it's a string column it needs the quotes. If it's an integer, MySQL will convert the string automatically.

Comment: @Barmar no, it doesn't. The variable will be interpreted as the string '$vuurwerkid' with single quotes. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512452/php-using-a-variable-inside-a-double-quotes

Comment: I don't see anythiing there that supports your claim. PHP never adds extra characters when it interpolates a variable into a string.

Comment: @Ali I was just answering his question on the exact problem. I didn't evaluate his code in terms of security.