# Embedding jquery popup in a php function

Tags: php, jquery, popup

Hi I have a jquery popup script I am trying to call in a php function.

The script calling the function is:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/sweetalert.css'>
<script src='js/sweetalert-dev.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>

<?php

include('functions/notification.php');

$notification_message = "There is a problem loading Smart Telecom at the moment.";

notify($notification_message);

?>
```

and the function call in notification.php:

```
<?php
function notify($message)
{
        $pop.= "<script>sweetAlert('". $message ."', 'Our Sincere apologies.', 'error');</script>";

        echo $pop;
}
```

?>

As it is, the pop up will display with an error about undefined variable $pop. If I try to disable error notifications, the popup doesn't display. if I do it without the concatenation, the popup also doesn't display.

Where am I going wrong?

UPDATE - SOLVED:

Got it to work. echoed "nbsp;", just before echoing $pop

Comment: That is because you are using `.=` in your `notify` function, `.=` means to add something to existing variable, but since the variable doesn't exist before your `$pop .=` line, it throws that undefined variable message. - Remove the dot from the `$pop .=` and you should be set.

Comment: extending @Epodax 's comment , simply change `$pop.=` to `$pop =`

Comment: When i do it without the concatenation, the popup does not display

Comment: try changing variable name.

Comment: changing variable name hasnt worked. it only displays when i place the concatenation, which makes no sense.

Comment: Have you checked the console for JS/jQuery errors whie the concat was removed from `$pop.=` ? / Inspect the html / js output from the function?

Comment: try changing code to this swal('". $message ."', 'Our Sincere apologies.', 'error');

Comment: No luck. I checked the console and it did have an uncaught error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null"

Comment: Well that is most likely the culprit then, when you remove the dot from `$pop .=` and run the function, what is the HTML output then? Is the syntax correct?

Comment: You could try to load jQuery before you load sweetalert, I'm not sure if that can be an issue in this case. So first <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script> instead of sweetalert

Comment: The syntax should be okay. when i run the script and and view page source, the css call is in red

Answer (score 0):

Ok so follow these steps to ensure the code is working, then check the pop issue:

1. Delete all data in the function to look like below:

   ```
   <?php
   function notify($message) {
       echo $message;
   } //output: data passed to $message variable should be displayed?>
   ```
2. if echo $message works then

   ```
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/sweetalert.css'>
   <!-- You must always place the jQuery first and then call functions or it will not work -->
   <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
   <script src='js/sweetalert-dev.js'></script>
   <?php
   function notify($message) {
       $pop = "<script>sweetAlert('$message', 'Our Sincere apologies.', 'error');</script>";//refer link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512452/php-using-a-variable-inside-a-double-quotes
       echo $pop;
   }?>
   ```

Comment: What have you changed and why? Code only answers rarely provide much insight for the OP and future visitors, a good answer explains what OP was doing wrong / what you have changed to make it work.

Comment: No luck. still not displaying popup

Comment: @user5898266, Refer this for variable with different variations:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp