# Set a class on an image within a loop

Tags: css, image, class

I am not experienced with coding at all. I just copy/paste template examples that I find on the internet and that has worked fine so far. However, there is a new problem that I am unable to solve.

The short question is, how can I set the css class of an image outside the <"img">?
For example, this is the code that I have, and does not work:

```
$class_key= "top".(string)$count;
$returnarray[$level_key]='<img class=$class_key src=http://somepic.jpg  width=100px height=100px/>';
```

If you want more details, I explain below:

I am layering images, and the position of the top images is randomly determined. I am using a css code to name and define the layers:

```
<style type="text/css">
.bottom
 {position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
 }
 .top1
 {
  position:absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
 }
.top2
 {
  position:absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
 }
```

And the variable $count is randomly determined. If I explicitly write class="top1" or class="top2", the code works.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Is there an upper limit to the likely value of `$count`?  Or could it go arbitrarily high?  More broadly, what larger goal are you trying to achieve?  And how does concatenating the count # to the `top` string help you achieve that?

Comment: Yes, $count is limited. Let's say I want a green background image, and on top of it a random (randomization is in php) image appears. With probability 1/2 the image is a red ball on the left side; and with probability 1/2 the image is a yellow ball on the right side. Moreover, this is repeated 10 times, and I need to keep track of the 10 outcome images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `PHP`...

You are using single quotes on `$returnarray[$level_key]='<img class=$class_key.../>';` then `$class_key` is not interpreted.

You can use the following:
Single quotes concatenating the variable:

```
`$returnarray[$level_key]='<img class="' . $class_key . '".../>';`
```

or double quotes

```
`$returnarray[$level_key]="<img class=\"{$class_key}\".../>";`
```

or another way using double quotes

```
`$returnarray[$level_key]="<img class=\"$class_key\".../>";`
```

See similar: [PHP: Using a variable inside a double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512452/php-using-a-variable-inside-a-double-quotes)

**To better manage your CSS:**

Add a generic class to your `$class_key`

```
$class_key= "img-top top".(string)$count;
```

Then the CSS rules will work for any image that contains `img-top` class:

```
.img-top{
  position:absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
 }
```

Also you can wrap your loop content inside a div

```
<div class="img-top">
   [loop logic]
</div>
```

And define the CSS for all images inside it:

```
.img-top img{
   position:absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 100px;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if the top1 and top2 have different characteristics? For example the position of top2 could be left: 150px;

Comment: Then you can set `.img-top.top2 { left: 150px; }`. or if you following the second example which the class is set outside the img you can set `.img-top img.top2 { left: 150px; }`...

Comment: I am sorry, it didn't work. I guess my question is a lot more basic than what you think. Why does after writing class=$class_key, class stays as "$class_key" and does not take the assigned value " "top".(string)$count " ?

Comment: Here we go, a different question. See my updated answer.