# use PHP variable in MySQL REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have multiple ids separated by `+` in one field of a row in a table
Like : (**123**+21654+412+12387)

I need Only EXACT MATCHES, (e.g.: only "123" and not "123 & 12387")

My code is like this:

```
$var = $value['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($this->dbh, "SELECT id FROM table
      WHERE id REGEXP '[[:<:]]$var[[:>:]]' ");
```

I have a problem with using a variable in REGEXP.

in case of :

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->dbh, "Select id FROM table
      WHERE id REGEXP '^$id|[\+]$id' ");
```

it works, but it does not return only exact matches

Comment: What is the exact problem you have with word boundaries? What is your MySQL version?

Comment: my MySQL version is: 5.5.32

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I Cannot put PHP variable in MySQL query which includes REGEXP

Comment: Well, `"SELECT id FROM table WHERE id REGEXP '[[:<:]]" . $var . "[[:>:]]' "` should work.

Comment: I think your question is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512452/php-using-a-variable-inside-a-double-quotes

Comment: Unfortunately not, It doesn't work.

Comment: [Both work](https://ideone.com/lVISk0).

Comment: Actually NOT, my problem is about using the variables in "REGEXP", which doesn't follow some common regex rules

Comment: Your question is *use PHP variable in MySQL REGEXP* and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512452/php-using-a-variable-inside-a-double-quotes solves that part. Whatever issue you have later, you have not explained it.

Comment: Can you try to put the query into variable, and echo that variable first? Make sure you get the query that you want.

Answer (score 0):

PHP tip:  "Interpolation" works these ways:

- `"...$var[...]..."` treats that as an array lookup for `$var[...]`.
- Without `[`, `$var` is assumed to be a scalar.
- `"...{$var}[...]..."` is what you need

This last example has braces `{}` to tell PHP to evaluate what is inside without being concerned about what follows.  More common usage:

```
$var = 'abc';
// I want to generate "abc123"
$bad  = "$var123";   // looks for variable 'var123'
$good = "{$var}123;  // correctly yields "abc123"
```

Your second attempt can be fixed thus:

```
REGEXP '(^|\+)$id(\+|$)'
```

meaning:

1. At the beginning or after a `+`,
2. Find $id (after interpolating),
3. And stop with a `+` or the end of the string.

Answer (score -1):

I'll go with :

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE id='123' OR id LIKE '123+%' OR id LIKE '%+123' OR id LIKE '%+123+%'";
```

The first condition will apply if you only have the value, the second if the field starts with the value, the third if the field ends with the value and the fourth if the value is in the middle of the field.

Comment: as I have multiple ids in one field I must use REGEXP!